# Redirecionar url "cortada" para url canonizada (Evitar url duplicada)

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável, redirecionamento-de-url

Quais são as configurações no .htaccess para que a url cortada tipo:
http://meusite.com/cidade/495/politica-de-priv

seja automaticamente redirecionado para a url (inteira) canonizada da página:
http://meusite.com/cidade/495/politica-de-privacidade

Evitando assim que o Google indexe as duas páginas.

Comment: Posta a parte do URL Rewrite do .htaccess

Comment: Acredito que seja esta a parte a ser corrigida:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /entry.php?w=$1&e_id=$2$3 [L]`

Comment: Se você utilizar corretamente o atributo rel=canonical em suas páginas não vai precisar se preocupar com URL duplicadas no índice do Google, é apenas uma sugestão, não sei se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Entendo. Mas além disso, gostaria de evitar que usuário altere a url, exemplo: http://meusite.com/cidade/495/insultos-ou-texto-aleatorio De modo que ao acessar a url modificada, ela seja restaurada para o link canonizado na barra de endereços do navegador.

Comment: Me parece que isso não é caso para .htaccess, e sim para se resolver no PHP, na mesma parte onde o número do post é processado. SImplesmente se não bater o URL com o BD, redireciona, talvez seja coisa de 1 ou 2 linhas de código no máximo.

Comment: Petrus, o melhor é você [edit] a pergunta, acrescentando as informações que está dando através de comentários, e depois notificar o outro usuário usando o arroba *"@UserName, editei a pergunta etc, etc,"* (o autor do post é sempre notificado)

Comment: @Bacco também pensei nisso, mas pelo que eu percebi, a url não é armazenada no BD, ela é gerada pelo php em cada requisição: 
`
 $url = "$prefix$weblog/$e_id/$stripped_title$extras";
`

Comment: Não me faz nenhum sentido essa afirmação. O número 495, o "politica-de-privacidade", etc estão salvos em algum lugar, não? Seria só comparar com ao URL sendo acessado.

Comment: De qq forma, definitivamente .htaccess não o caminho pra isso. Se puder postar a parte que pega o URL e mostra a postagem certa, podemos tentar te ajudar. Está usando alguma estrutura pronta, como wordpress ou similares?

Comment: @brasofilo vou editar a pergunta assim que conseguir expressar o problema de maneira concisa, os comentários estão ajudando.

Comment: @Bacco O número "495" sim, é o $e_id. o "politica-de-privacidade" é gerado a partir do título da postagem "Política de Privacidade", se eu mudo o título, a url muda automaticamente. O que eu quis dize é que a url não está armazenada de forma independente em uma coluna da tabela separada.

Comment: @Bacco Estou usando o sistema "Bloghoster". No Wordpress ele já faz isso por padrão. Estou tentando adaptar essa funcionalidade para esse sistema.

Comment: Eu tenho impressão que uma coisa parecida com isso resolveria `if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $url ) { header( "Location: $url"  ) }` supondo que $url seja gerado desta maneira que você postou. Ou seja, se o que a pessoa requisitou não for o URL correto, redireciona. Claro que no caso teria que remontar o URL pelo ID obtido. Talvez já tenha alguma função no próprio Bloghoster que ao menos gere o url. É uma coisa bem simples de se fazer, mas que depende unica e exclusivamente de se ver o código relevante que processa o URL para poder responder.

Comment: @Bacco acredito que esta seja a parte do código que vocês está se referindo: [entry.php] (http://pastebin.com/afcEdnjX) e [functions.php] (http://pastebin.com/80A8HqSe)

Comment: @PetrusCintraKamaleao me parece que $entry_info tem tudo o que vc precisa, seria só comparar o slug se bate com o title mesmo, e por essa lógica no redirect que já tem lá. Não tentei entender direito algumas coisas repetidas nesse código, pq teria que ler com calma, mas dá pra enxugar ele bem, e funcionar como você quer com bem poucas linhas, seria bem o que eu disse no comentário anterior mesmo.